# how to list only the name of the baselines and name of the stream from particular component in UCM ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

Is there any way that I can list all baselines' name and stream name for those baselines from a particular component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic command would be [`cleartool lsbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsbl.htm):

```
cleartool lsbl -comp aComponent@\aPVob
```

You can then use [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) to display the stream as well as the baseline.

```
cleartool lsbl -fmt "%n %[bl_stream]Xp\n" -comp aComponent@\aPVob
```

A similar command would be:

```
cleartool lsbl -tree -comp aComponent@\aPVob
```

(to see the stream, and its location within the UCM project).

If that doesn't work, you can, for each baseline returned by the first command, do a:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%n %[bl_stream]Xp\n" aBaseline@\aPVob
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have to list about 50 baselines and its associated stream in a component.
I am not sure what you meant by [bl_stream]Xp\n.

Comment: @knm that would display the name of the stream where the baseline has been created, as documented at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm. That way, you list both baseline *and* stream for a given component.